Avoid false infinity without first using Simplify
Sometimes, when you solve some equations, Solve (or other relevant functions) returns solutions containing terms superficially diverge for some parameters. You know the solutions are guaranteed to be finite from the background of your problem, but if you try to directly plot the solutions or what not, all you get is a bunch of infinity warnings without useful results.
In simple cases, the issue can be cured using Simplify. However, the time consumption of Simplify can be intolerable in complicated cases.
Is there any work around to avoid false infinity without first using Simplify? There're some similar questions on this site but they don't seem to address my question.

Edit: Michael E2's comment on using Limit is really helpful. I find it works pretty well in many cases.
Here I provide a not so small example since the problem doesn't exist in really simple cases (or there is but I cannot construct such an example at the time):
Solve[(t1 - 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) == -I n1 && (r2 - r1) == I n1 && 
  E^(I k) (t2 - t1) == -I n2 && E^(-I  k) (r3 - r2) == I n2 && 
  E^(I 2 k) (t3 - t2) == -I n3 && E^(-I 2 k) (r4 - r3) == I n3 && 
  E^(I 3 k) (t4 - t3) == -I n4 && E^(-I 3 k) (r5 - r4) == I n4 &&
  E^(I 4 k) (t5 - t4) == -I n5 && E^(-I 4 k) (r6 - r5) == I n5 &&
  E^(I 5 k) (t6 - t5) == -I n6 && E^(-I 5 k) (r7 - r6) == I n6 &&
  E^(I 6 k) (t7 - t6) == -I n7 && E^(-I 6 k) (0 - r7) == I n7 &&
  w n1 == 1/2 ((t1 + 1) + (r2 + r1)) + (w0 - I f) n1 + J1 n2 && 
  w n2 == 
   1/2 (E^(I  k) (t2 + t1) + E^(-I k) (r3 + r2)) + 
    J1 n1 + (w0 - I f) n2 + J2 n3 && 
  w n3 == 
   1/2 (E^(I  2 k) (t3 + t2) + E^(-I 2 k) (r4 + r3)) + 
    J2 n2 + (w0 - I f) n3 + J1 n4 && 
  w n4 == 
   1/2 (E^(I  3 k) (t4 + t3) + E^(-I 3 k) (r5 + r4)) + 
    J1 n3 + (w0 - I f) n4 + J2 n5 && 
  w n5 == 
   1/2 (E^(I 4 k) (t5 + t4) + E^(-I 4 k) (r6 + r5)) + 
    J2 n4 + (w0 - I f) n5 + J1 n6 && 
  w n6 == 
   1/2 (E^(I 5 k) (t6 + t5) + E^(-I 5 k) (r7 + r6)) + 
    J1 n5 + (w0 - I f)  n6 + J2 n7 && 
  w n7 == 
   1/2 (E^(I 6 k) (t7 + t6) + E^(-I 6 k) (0 + r7)) + 
    J2 n6 + (w0 - I f) n7, {t1, r1, t2, r2, t3, r3, t4, r4, t5, r5,
   t6, r6, t7, r7, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7}]

Sorry for the length of code. It most probably can be written more concisely using matrix, but I'm not really fluent at that now.
False infinity appears at, for example:
t1/.{f -> 0, J2 -> 0, w -> w0, k -> 3 \[Pi]/2}
Out: {Indeterminate}

This example problem can easily scale to have many more variables, when Simplify is intolerable. Using Limit inside Plot can also increase time significantly, but I haven't tested extensively to give any meaningful performance comparison between Limit and Simplify.
I wonder if there're other work around besides Limit. Or how to increase performance by something like "use Limit only at problematic points"?
Answer tailored for specific case is helpful indeed, but a general idea would be more helpful.

Related:
How to avoid infinities in the following example?
Force Mathematica to simplify a function to avoid infinities

Please provide one or two small examples that show this problem.

I use Limit[].

For posterity, it can be helpful to provide a list of links to the similar questions, even if they do not quite address your question.

@Bill @Tapiocaweasel, post edited as requested. @Michael E2, your advice is really helpful, yet I wonder how to overcome the performance cost of nesting Limit inside, for example, Plot, in complicated cases.

As a work-around, you could apply {f -> 0, J2 -> 0, w -> w0, k -> 3 \[Pi]/2} to the set of equations and then use `Solve".  Doing so is fast and produces no errors, at least for the given set of values.

Another work-around is to use Cancel instead of Simplify, although this is not as fast as the option in my previous comment.  Cancel[t1]/.{f -> 0, J2 -> 0, w -> w0, k -> 3 \[Pi]/2}.

@bbgodfrey, Cancel is new to me, thanks for pointing out.

Several methods exist to avoid the false infinity noted in the question.  For notational simplicity, define
eqs = List @@ (the first argument in `Solve` above);
var = {t1, r1, t2, r2, t3, r3, t4, r4, t5, r5, t6, r6, t7, r7, n1, n2,
    n3, n4, n5, n6, n7};
param = {f -> 0, J2 -> 0, w -> w0, k -> 3 Pi/2};

Then my first suggestion in the comments,
Timing[Chop[t1 /. NSolve[eqs /. param, var]]]
(* {0.015625, {(0.398942 (-6.02651 - 1.97349 J1 + 10.4934 J1^2 - 6. J1^3 + 
    1. J1^4))/(16. - 32. J1 + 24. J1^2 - 8. J1^3 + 1. J1^4)}} *)

quickly provides a numerical solution.  However,
Timing[t1 /. Solve[eqs /. param, var]]
(* {0.03125, {-((-Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[2] J1 - Sqrt[2] J1^2 + 2 Sqrt[Pi])/
    (2 (-2 + J1)^2 Sqrt[Pi]))}} *)

provides a compact symbolic solution and takes only twice as long.  Using Limit, as commented by Michael_E2, works well but requires 23.6 seconds to produce the same result.
Timing[Simplify[Cancel[t1 /. Solve[eqs, var]] /. param]]

My second suggestion in the comments, to use Cancel, is no faster, requiring 24.9 seconds to produce the same result.
Timing[Simplify[Cancel[t1 /. Solve[eqs, var]] /. param]]

Slowest of all at 38.8 seconds is the brute-force approach of applying Simplify directly to the lengthy expression for t1 provided by Solve.
Timing[Simplify[Simplify[t1 /. Solve[eqs, var]] /. param]]

I also experimented a bit with LinearSolve but it too produces a false infinity unless treated by one of the methods described above.  Nonetheless, because the arrays fed into LinearSolve are sparce, it is possible that some manipulation of the matrices might produce faster solutions without a false infinity, depending on what results are desired.

Thanks for your answer! Such an extensive comparison is really helpful.
